# What does public static void mean? What is a class?

Tags: java

I just accepted that all my programs I made have to start with this. Then I was looking at a example #2 [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62) regarding generation of a random number.

```
import java.util.Random;

/** Generate random integers in a certain range. */
public final class RandomRange {

  public static final void main(String... aArgs){
    log("Generating random integers in the range 1..10.");

    int START = 1;
    int END = 10;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10; ++idx){
      showRandomInteger(START, END, random);
    }

    log("Done.");
  }

  private static void showRandomInteger(int aStart, int aEnd, Random aRandom){
    if (aStart > aEnd) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start cannot exceed End.");
    }
    //get the range, casting to long to avoid overflow problems
    long range = (long)aEnd - (long)aStart + 1;
    // compute a fraction of the range, 0 <= frac < range
    long fraction = (long)(range * aRandom.nextDouble());
    int randomNumber =  (int)(fraction + aStart);    
    log("Generated : " + randomNumber);
  }

  private static void log(String aMessage){
    System.out.println(aMessage);
  }
}
```

I noticed that this had a public static void and a private static void. Why not just combine the code into one thing under public static void? More importantly, what do these mean? I did research and saw the word "class" pop up often. What is a class? I hope my question meets the guidelines, this is my first time posting here. Thanks.

Comment: You should consider reading the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial)

Comment: Sorry, but thhis is **far** outside the scope of this place. You are asking for the basics of OOP and Java, I would suggest simply reading the apropriate books or taking a course...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: @HungPV, Your link is not linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not fully correct, it is very simplified:

Mostly one class equals one file. Even so they can access each other (if in the same project/folder) Here are 3 example classes:

Class withe the main method:

```
 package ooexample;

    public class OOExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int min = 2;
        int max = 101;

        // use of static method
        int randomNumberA = MyMath.generateRandomNumber(min, max);

        // use of non static method
        RandomNumberGenerator generator = new RandomNumberGenerator();
        int randomNumberB = generator.randomNumber(min, max);

        /**
        * does not work, method is private, can not be accessed from an outise class
        * only RandomNumberGenerator can access it
        */        
        // generator.printSomeNumber(123);
    }
}
```

Class with a static method. The method can be access by writing classname.nameOfStaticMethod(...) see main method.

```
package ooexample;

public class MyMath {

    public static int generateRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
        return min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
    }
}
```

Class without static method. You have to create the class in the main method, using the new operator and assign the created class to a variable. Then you can use the variable to access PUBLIC methods of that class. You can not access private methods anywhere else but inside of the class itself. See main method.

```
package ooexample;

public class RandomNumberGenerator {

    public RandomNumberGenerator() {

    }

    public int randomNumber(int min, int max) {
        int randomNumber = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
        printSomeNumber(randomNumber);

        return randomNumber;
    }

    private void printSomeNumber(int number) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I will assume you asked here because you wanted a concise answer that  gives you some intuition, rather than a deep dive into [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) which you can pull from the tutorial.

A `class` is a template from which objects are built. However, until you  understand [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), the `class` is just a necessary wrapper around the imperative code you are writing because Java requires all code to live inside a class.

`public` means the method is publicly accessible. Methods which are defined in classes other than this one can access it. `private` has the opposite meaning.

`static` means that this is a class-level function that is not tied to any particular instance of the class.

`void` means the method returns nothing.

You can certainly put all the code under a single method, but that carries at least the following problems.

1. Code is harder to read because the intent of the code is hidden by the details of the implementation.
2. Code is harder to reuse because you have to copy and paste whenever you need the same functionality in multiple places.